# Function to get final price of products Magento 2.4.6

Tags: php, price, magento2.4.6, function

I am using the following code to get from magento 2.4.6 product's final price, simple or configurable, to a feed json file. Final price I mean that I need the lower discounted price in product, either coming from special price or from a catalog rule.

```
public function addPriceData(StoreInterface $store, $product, array &$data, array $childProducts): void
{
    $priceData = $this->prices->getPriceData(
        $store,
        $product,
        $childProducts
    );

    $data['Prices'] = $priceData['Prices'];
    $data['SalePrices'] = $priceData['SalePrices'];
    $data['GroupPrices'] = $priceData['GroupPrices'];
}
```

But it happens something wired. Some of my products get the right price some are not. It returns to me nothing. I have no error in logs.

Any help please to make my function better?

Comment: I assume this will help you :- https://www.integerbyteblog.in/magento/product-price-in-magento-2/